# C++ template - non member functions

Tags: c++, templates

I am trying to implement `insertOrdered` class method for double-linked list in C++ (I am newbie to C++). The issue are errors which originate from defined util functions (non class functions) which are called from `insertOrdered`method. The g++ compiler shows the errors which are written here as comments: //error: ....

Can someone tell me how to resolve the errors. Thanks.

LinkedList.h:

```
template <typename T>
class LinkedList 
{
   public:
       class Node 
       {
           public:
             Node* next;
             Node* prev;
             T data;

           ...
       }

       void insertOrdered(const T& newData);

   private:
      Node* head;
       
   ...
}
```

Task.h:

```
#include "LinkedList.h"

template <typename T>
bool insertWhenEmpty(LinkedList<T> list, const T& data)
{
     auto newNode = new LinkedList<T>::Node(data); //error: expected type-specifier
     ....
}

template <typename T>
void insertBefore(LinkedList<T> list, LinkedList<T>::Node curr, const T& data)
{
   //error: LinkedList<T>::Node curr -> use the 'typename' keyword to treat nontype "LinkedList<T>::Node [with T=T]" as a type in a dependent context
   ....
}
     
template <typename T>
void LinkedList<T>::insertOrdered(const T& newData)
{
    if (insertWhenEmpty(this, newData))
       return;

    ....
    auto curr = this->head;
    insertBefore(this, curr, newData);
    ....
}
```

Comment: `var` is not a C++ keyword

Comment: You might also want to pass the list by reference.

Comment: Code edited. var -> auto.

Comment: And please see the question "Where and why do I have to put the "template" and "typename" keywords?" in the list of "Related" questions on the right side. And perhaps do what the error message ask you to do to solve it?

Comment: @dajuric You missed one of the uses of `var` in `insertWhenEmpty`.